# Updating sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, updating

Im trying to make an update form using php and updating the sql database but it seems not to work here. I tried updating the form and then it should say that its updated but it doesn't want to work. I need help please. Thanks

```
<?php
include 'connections/connection.php';

$updateinfo = @$_POST['update'];

$get_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer");
$id = @$_REQUEST['id'];
$get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_info);
$db_cname = $get_row['customer_name'];
$db_cemail = $get_row['customer_email'];
$db_caddress = $get_row['customer_address'];
$db_cphone = $get_row['customer_phone'];

  if ($updateinfo) {
    $cname = strip_tags(@$_POST['cname']); 
    $cemail = strip_tags(@$_POST['cemail']);
    $caddress = strip_tags(@$_POST['caddress']);
    $cphone = strip_tags(@$_POST['cphone']); 

    //Submit the form to the database
    $info_submit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET customer_name='$cname', customer_email='$cemail', customer_address='$caddress', customer_phone='$cphone' WHERE id='$id'") or die("Error! " . mysql_error());
    echo "updated!";
   }
  else
 {
   echo "error " . mysql_error();
}
?>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Customer Modification</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5" width="30%" style="margin-top:100px;" align="center" bgcolor="#FFB13C">
        <form action="edit.php" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Customer Name:*</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="cname" value="<?php echo $db_cname; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Customer Email:*</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="cemail" value="<?php echo $db_cemail; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Customer Address:*</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="caddress"  value="<?php echo $db_caddress; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Customer Phone:*</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="50" name="cphone" value="<?php echo $db_cphone; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Edit"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>

    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development. You are also suppressing possible errors using the `@` symbol.

Comment: Obligatory "mysql is being deprecated. Please start using mysqli or PDO".

Comment: "WHERE id='$id'"....it's been a while since I worked with PHP but doesn't that translate to...if say the id is 5...WHERE id='5'....IDs are typicall stored as ints...so if that's how it gets interpolated...the quotes would probably throw it off.

Comment: Don't just say that it doesn't work. Say what _does_ happen. Are you hitting your `or die` statement? If so, what error is provided?